# Where to put shell script/function? .bashrc or bin?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am learning Linux commands and I learnt that you can write a shell script and put in a customized directory (e.g. `~/bin/` ) and export to `$PATH` or you can write it as a shell function and put in `.bashrc` file.

If I may ask, what is the right situation or reason to use either? which one is more recommended?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

when you want something that modifies your shell environment (e.g. your ENV variables, your prompt etc..), it is better to make it a function that stays in your .bashrc. Typically, one of the functions I often use, is one that changes my environment for working with `/usr/local` or `/opt` etc.. updating the `$PATH`, `$LD_PATH`, `$PYTHON_PATH` orders.

When you make a whole program that takes advantage of shell scripting, then it is better in its own file, in a bin/ directory. Typically, you want to automatize a task, filter output using a complex piping of seds and awks (e.g. count the number of different IPs appear in the ssh logs?) that makes a good use case of a script.

Answer (score 1):

Functions work better as small, self-contained blocks. Scripts work better for longer, more complex tasks (which could be composed of smaller functions itself). Keep in mind that a script stored in `~/bin` will be launched in a separate processes (unless you take the effort to run it as `source myScript` instead).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a whole script (even a small one) I usually put it in `~/bin`. If it's on the order of an alias it goes in the bashrc.